# Make 'shadowrun-5e' a synonym of 'shadowrun-sr5'

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonymization

The [shadowrun-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadowrun-5e) has only two questions, and appears to be synonymous with [shadowrun-sr5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadowrun-sr5). It should be made a synonym of the much more popular tag [shadowrun-sr5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadowrun-sr5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for noticing that. Done and done!